# Using hits.hitNumber to get hits occurring after a specific hit

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery

I want to return all the add to cart event occurring after a visitor hit a specific page during a session.

Using the google_analytics_sample from the demo shop account as a reference and with the following query

```
   SELECT
    hits.eCommerceAction.action_type,
    hits.hitNumber
    FROM
    `bigquery-public-data.google_analytics_sample.ga_sessions_20170801` AS GA, UNNEST(GA.hits) AS hits
where 
hits.eCommerceAction.action_type = "2"
```

What query do I need to write to return only the Add to Cart even occurring after a specific page view hit? Let say `REGEXP_CONTAINS(hits.page.pagePath, r'asearch')` for example.

Basically I would need to do something like this

```
where (hits.eCommerceAction.action_type = 2 and hits.hitNumber) > REGEXP_CONTAINS(hits.page.pagePath, r'asearch') and hits.hitNumber)
```

But I'm not sure how I should articulate this with my query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it makes sense to operate within a subquery instead of cross joining with hits array. This saves resources and keeps the natural boundaries of the array.

In the solution here I'm subquerying some info from the wanted hits and restrict them by a nested subquery on the very same array:

```sql
SELECT
  fullvisitorid, -- identify user
  visitstarttime, -- identify session per user
  -- feed output of subquery back into an array
  array(SELECT AS STRUCT
    hitNumber, page.pagePath, eventInfo.eventAction
  FROM GA.hits 
  WHERE
    -- add to cart
    eCommerceAction.action_type = "3"
    -- and its hitnumber must be over the min hitnumber of 'asearch'
    AND hitnumber > (SELECT MIN(hitnumber) FROM GA.hits WHERE REGEXP_CONTAINS(page.pagePath, r'asearch')) 
  ORDER BY hitnumber) AS myHits
FROM
  `bigquery-public-data.google_analytics_sample.ga_sessions_20170801` AS GA
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(1)>0 FROM GA.hits WHERE eCommerceAction.action_type = "3")
  AND (SELECT COUNT(1)>0 FROM GA.hits WHERE REGEXP_CONTAINS(page.pagePath, r'asearch') )
LIMIT 1000
```

The output is 3 fields: fullvisitorid + visitstarttime to identify a session as well as an array containing the desired hits.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "keeps the natural boundaries of the array."?

Comment: Also could you explain more "feed output of subquery back into an array"?

Comment: When you cross join with the array you're essentially bringing its fields up to table level - but then it's no array anymore and an aggregation or window function `over ()` would run over the entire table. If you do a subselect you only aggregate or window this array and that's it.

Comment: The function `array()` usually takes it's input from subqueries. Usually you can only return 1 element back from a subquery. But you can return more if you put them into an array - which effectively is one element again.